# Creating an array table so customers can choose an item to purchase

Tags: java, arrays

I created a "mock" ordering system to take customer input based off of their replies to JoptionPane windows.

Such as "What type of card deck to you wish to purchase Standard, Uno, or Rook?" They input their answer and my system records it and a price is associated later on.

I am now wanting to put the items in an array allowing me to just go ahead and assign a price for example a customer wants to order a "Blue, Standard, Plastic Deck of cards"  the price I want associated with this order would be $3.00.

I have tried to create the products in the main method and then in a Card class and sub classes.  I am just wondering if I am on the right track or if I need to head a different route to accomplish this.

```
//Array
class DiamondCards{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    
Card[] card = new Card[6];

// Fill in Cards
card[0] = new Card("Laminated Coating", "Standard", 2);
card[1] = new Card("Laminated Coating", "Uno", 2.50);
card[2] = new Card("Laminated Coating", "Rook", 2.75);
card[3] = new Card("Plastic Card", "Standard", 3);
card[4] = new Card("Plastic Card", "Uno", 3.50);
card[5] = new Card("Plastic Card", "Rook", 3.75);
// Card Super Class
static public class Card{
    public String coatingType;
    public String deckType;
    public double cost;    
    
public Card(String coatingType, String deckType, 
double cost){

    this.coatingType = coatingType;
    this.deckType = deckType;
    this.cost = cost;

    }
}
```

Comment: means u need to derive price of that product what is selected by customer is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good.

To make it better you can make the `Card` properties private and add setter and getter methods. Your IDE does this for free. Let's say you want to make the cost evaluation dynamic you don't have to change `Card`'s API.

Answer (score 1):

Use `List` instead of array. Arrays are fixed size, if you want to resize an array you need to create a new one and copy all elements but it's expensive operation.

```
List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

// Fill in Cards
cards.add(new Card("Laminated Coating", "Standard", 2));
cards.add(new Card("Laminated Coating", "Uno", 2.50));
cards.add(new Card("Laminated Coating", "Rook", 2.75));
cards.add(new Card("Plastic Card", "Standard", 3));
cards.add(new Card("Plastic Card", "Uno", 3.50));
cards.add(new Card("Plastic Card", "Rook", 3.75));
```

then add a new one

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are on the right track.

Use ArrayList or Vector to get more flexible collection.

You need another collection for the items that a customer selected.

You need to add "color" if the customer can select color like 'Blue'

The list of items selected by the customer might be a list of objects where each object has two members: Card and quantity.